# Battery Use Grouped By Application

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

Is there a way (other than powertop) I can see how much of my laptop battery's charge was used for each application over the current discharge cycle similar to how Android Marshmallow does?

Answer (score 0):

This information is not provided by any specific kernel interface and has to be estimated (guessed) manually using statistics such as CPU run time, I/O activity etc.  This requires calibrating the system to get good estimates based on the hardware design, so there is no easy generic way of doing this.  So the answer is, in theory it is possible to get some kind of vague estimate, but in practice it is non-trivial and is not going to be implemented.